# AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'mouse_pos'

Tags: events, pygame, attributes, attributeerror, mouse-position

I simply want to save the mouse position at every instant. Why is this simple code not working?

```
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
screen.fill((255,255,255))

while True:
    ev = pygame.event.get()
    for event in ev:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type != pygame.NOEVENT:
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()      
            x, y = event.mouse_pos
            print(x, y)
```

Comment: This code works, except for the typo `x, y = event.mouse_pos` which should be `x, y = mouse_pos`.  And you need to handle `pygame.QUIT` event.  I'm not sure you need to have the point-tracking inside the `!= NOEVENT` block though.

Comment: diffferent events have different types and different elements. Some events have mouse position, others pressed key and others may have something different. You have to check if you have `event.type` which may have `mouse_pos` before you can get `event.mouse_pos` - see documentation [events](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mouse position can be tracked outside of the event processing loop.

```
import pygame
import sys

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
screen.fill((255,255,255))

last_pos = (-1,-1)

while True:
    # handle user events
    ev = pygame.event.get()
    for event in ev:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    # track the mouse co-ords
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if ( mouse_pos != last_pos ):
        x,y = mouse_pos
        print(x, y)
        last_pos = mouse_pos
```